# Tab Between Components

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I'm playing around with the physics login form from [Doug Mccune's blog](http://dougmccune.com/blog/2008/02/26/examples-from-my-360flex-session-using-open-source-community-projects/)

I'm trying to make it so that after I finish typing the username I can hit the tab key to go to the password field, and again to go to the login button.  I'm a bit of a n00b with flex, so I assumed setting the tabIndex properties would solve that, but it doesn't.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
After a little further investigation, the problem appears to lie with PhysicsContainer.  If the physics container is removed, the tabbing works without issue.  Unfortunately that also defeats the point of the whole project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also need to set the tabEnabled property of the loginBtn as well.

If that doesn't fix it, I'd try looking at the FocusManager:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/langref/mx/managers/FocusManager.html

Comment: Thanks for the nudge in the right direction.  Perhaps when I have time I can figure out how to get PhysicsContainer to work with FocusManager